# Sophisticated use of Nest: Using the current iteration number and referring to outer lists

Tags: functional-style, map, iterators

I want to write an iterative algorithm on the base of Nest (avoiding usage of cycles) to create an expression of the type
$$
x^{a_1x^{a_2x^{\ldots}}}
$$
where the numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots $ are given in a list *apriori*.
The problem is that I don't know how to refer to Nest's current iteration number. For example, $x^{x^{x}}$ is computed by

```
Nest[x^(#) &, x, 3]
```

How do I refer to a[[i]] in the expression x^(#) & ?

Comment: Look up `Fold`, it should help.

Comment: @C.E. So I thought `Fold[Power, x, Thread[x list]]`, or `Fold[#1^#2 &, x, {a x, b x, c x, d x}]` but that's not the same.

Comment: You could do: `Fold[#2^#1&, x Append[Reverse@Array[a, 10], 1]]` . Replace `Array[a, 10]` with the list of your interest.

Comment: @JHM, your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Veliko It does for me, try clearing `x` and `a` (or quitting the kernel).

Comment: yep, JHM's code compiles fine

Comment: If you have to use Nest you can do 'a = {a3, a2, a1, 1};  i = 1; Nest[x^(a[[i++]] #)&, x, 3]'?

Comment: @kglr thank you, this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 a = {a3, a2, a1};
 i = 1; Nest[x^(a[[i++]] #)&, x, 3]
```

Or

```
 b = {a1, a2, a3};
 i = 3; Nest[x^(b[[i--]] #)&, x, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way using `Fold` is to use the product of `x` and `alist` as the third argument

```
alist = {a1, a2, a3};

Fold[#1^#2 &, x, x*alist]
```

$$\left(\left(x^{a_1 x}\right){}^{a_2 x}\right){}^{a_3 x}$$